# React: Getting index of mapped items outside component

Tags: reactjs

I'm quite new to React and I'm trying to add pagination dots to a carousel component that I created using react-swipable. From react-swipeable documentation I already implemented working next/previous buttons, but I can't figure out how to implement the pagination dots in the same format.

I'm not sure if I'm thinking the right way, but I figured that if I could read the index of the mapped items, I could use it to show the right item by its index.

The component uses a reducer and I'm stuck on getting the index from the mapped items into the switch statement and use it there. I think I'm just not looking in the right direction, because I tried everything I could think of and googled for hours trying to find the answer, finding no similar situations/questions at all. Does any of you have an idea on how to show the right slide according to the pagination-button clicked? (so clicking the second pagination button, should show the second slide)

So I added a DOT case to the switch statement, which has an if-statement inside to decide whether to slide in next or previous direction. Than I wanted 'pos' to change to the clicked items index.

Sorry if it's a dumb question, I'm just a beginner and it's a little confusing for me sometimes.

Here's my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Swipeable } from "react-swipeable";

const NEXT = "NEXT";
const PREV = "PREV";
const DOT = "DOT";

function getOrder({ index, pos, numItems }) {
  return index - pos < 0 ? numItems - Math.abs(index - pos) : index - pos;
}

const initialState = { pos: 0, sliding: false, dir: NEXT };

const CarouselContainer = styled.ul`
  display: flex;
  transition: ${(props) => (props.sliding ? "none" : "transform 1s ease")};
  transform: ${(props) => {
    if (!props.sliding) return "translateX(calc(-100%))";
    if (props.dir === PREV) return "translateX(calc(2 * (-100%)))";
    return "translateX(0%)";
  }};
`;

function Carousel(props) {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const numItems = React.Children.count(props.children);
  const index = props.children;

  function Slide(dir) {
    dispatch({ type: dir, numItems });
    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch({ type: "stopSliding" });
    }, 50);
  }

  const config = {
    onSwipedLeft: () => Slide(NEXT),
    onSwipedRight: () => Slide(PREV),
    preventDefaultTouchmoveEvent: true,
    trackMouse: true,
  };

  return (
    <Swipeable {...config}>
      <div>
        <CarouselContainer dir={state.dir} sliding={state.sliding}>
          {React.Children.map(props.children, (child, index) => (
            <li
              key={index}
              order={getOrder({ index: index, pos: state.pos, numItems })}
              style={{ order: `${getOrder({ index: index, pos: state.pos, numItems })}` }}
            >
              {child}
            </li>
          ))}
        </CarouselContainer>
      </div>

      <ul>
        <li onClick={() => Slide(PREV)}>Vorige</li>
        <li onClick={() => Slide(NEXT)}>Volgende</li>
      </ul>

      <ul className={styles.pagination}>
        {React.Children.map(props.children, (dot, index) => (
          <li
            key={index}
            onClick={() => {
              Slide(DOT);
            }}
          >
          {dot}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </Swipeable>
  );
}

function reducer(state, { type, numItems }) {
  switch (type) {
    case "reset":
      return initialState;
    case PREV:
      return {
        ...state,
        dir: PREV,
        sliding: true,
        pos: state.pos === 0 ? numItems - 1 : state.pos - 1,
      };
    case NEXT:
      return {
        ...state,
        dir: NEXT,
        sliding: true,
        pos: state.pos === numItems - 1 ? 0 : state.pos + 1,
      };
    case DOT:
      if (state.pos > state.index) {
        return {
          ...state,
          dir: PREV,
          sliding: true,
          pos: state.index,
        };

      if (state.pos < state.index) {
        return {
          ...state,
          dir: NEXT,
          sliding: true,
          pos: state.index,
        };
      }
    case "stopSliding":
      return { ...state, sliding: false };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default Carousel;
```

Comment: Why you just can't pass the index to Slide function like this: Slide(DOT, index); and then dispatch it to the reducer and use it anywhere. Will it work for you?

Comment: @Telary Thank you! sometimes it's just such a small thing I'm missing! I actually tried this, but made a mistake in dispatching it. Now it finally works! I'm happy :-)

Answer (score 1):

@Telary's hint made me solve the problem! I can't mark his comment as an anwer, so here it is:

```
function Carousel(props) {
  const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(reducer, initialState);
  const numItems = React.Children.count(props.children);
  const index = props.children;

  function Slide(dir, index) {
    dispatch({ type: dir, numItems, index });
    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch({ type: "stopSliding" });
    }, 50);
  }

  const config = {
    onSwipedLeft: () => Slide(NEXT),
    onSwipedRight: () => Slide(PREV),
    preventDefaultTouchmoveEvent: true,
    trackMouse: true,
  };

  return (
    <Swipeable {...config}>
      <div>
        <CarouselContainer dir={state.dir} sliding={state.sliding}>
          {React.Children.map(props.children, (child, index) => (
            <li
              key={index}
              order={getOrder({ index: index, pos: state.pos, numItems })}
              style={{ order: `${getOrder({ index: index, pos: state.pos, numItems })}` }}
            >
              {child}
            </li>
          ))}
        </CarouselContainer>
      </div>

      <ul>
        <li onClick={() => Slide(PREV)}>Vorige</li>
        <li onClick={() => Slide(NEXT)}>Volgende</li>
      </ul>

      <ul className={styles.pagination}>
        {React.Children.map(props.children, (dot, index) => (
          <li
            key={index}
            onClick={() => {
              Slide(DOT, index);
            }}
          >
          {dot}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </Swipeable>
  );
}

function reducer(state, { type, numItems }) {
  switch (type) {
    case "reset":
      return initialState;
    case PREV:
      return {
        ...state,
        dir: PREV,
        sliding: true,
        pos: state.pos === 0 ? numItems - 1 : state.pos - 1,
      };
    case NEXT:
      return {
        ...state,
        dir: NEXT,
        sliding: true,
        pos: state.pos === numItems - 1 ? 0 : state.pos + 1,
      };
    case DOT:
      if (state.pos > state.index) {
        return {
          ...state,
          dir: PREV,
          sliding: true,
          pos: state.index,
        };

      if (state.pos < state.index) {
        return {
          ...state,
          dir: NEXT,
          sliding: true,
          pos: state.index,
        };
      }
    case "stopSliding":
      return { ...state, sliding: false };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default Carousel;
```